# Split json file as parent and multiple child

Tags: json, jq

I have json file which will grow in future so i want to split it as parent and child in one folder and refer all child in parent file so i could manage multiple file rather than one big file. I am using this file for configurations

Following is example to demonstrate my requirement

**Main.json**

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

I want to split like below

**Parent.json**

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            "$ref": "book1.json",
            "$ref": "book2.json"
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

**book1.json**

```
{
    "category": "reference",
    "author": "Nigel Rees",
    "title": "Sayings of the Century",
    "price": 8.95
}
```

I tried to display parent file but its giving error, I want that parent.json should display as main.json

```
# jq . parent.json
parse error: ':' not as part of an object at line 10, column 19
```

Comment: your `Parent.json` is invalid JSON - `"book": [ ... ]` contains records which supposed to be listed in object, i.e.: `"book": { ... }`

Comment: @Dmitry book is array so i am referring array elements, you can compare with Main.json

Comment: yes, it's an array, so it cannot contain objects records in the format `"label": "value"`, only objects do. If you like to list your entries as they spelled (i.e. with labels), then it should be like this `"book": [ {"$ref": "book1.json"}, {"$ref": "book2.json"} ]`

Comment: Thanks for quick response, its not to only display json file i want to use parent.json as config file for other applications, So for those applications Main.json and Parent.json should be same. Splitting this will only help maintenance of this file.

Comment: yes, I understood your request right - and provided a solution (using my tool). but those are points you need to fix: 1. `Parent.json` is _invalid JSON_ - so you have to fix it either way (like in my 1st, or like in my 2nd comment). 2. Then, depending on the fixed format, you can apply the provided solution. In case of the latter fix, the solution would be: **`<Parent.json jtc -w'<book>l<ref>l:<b>v[-1]' -eu cat {{b}} \;`**

Comment: So we dont have out of box syntax in json which support this kind of merging. As i want my application just refer to parent.json and get that updated view. it mean before exposing to application i have to run above commands to create consolidated view.

Comment: hmm. But then there's a dilemma: if you like to keep your `Parent.json` not in a JSON compliant format (so it'll be partially compliant), then you cannot use json tools to parse it right (cause the file violates JSON semantic). Thus you have to rely on text based tools (like `awk`, `sed`) to perform required substitution. But then, you'll be exposed to risk of facing false positives/negatives sooner of later (cause those text aware tools do not understand/handle recurrent/nested formats).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding @Dmitry's points (that `[ "$ref": "book1.json" ]` is not valid JSON), why don't you instead have

```
[
  { "$ref": "book1.json" },
  { "$ref": "book2.json" },
  ...
]
```

Beyond this, what you're asking for is a program that generates multiple files, one of which is Parent.json and the rest of which are book*n*.json. Since `jq` can only provide output via one stream, you could generate one line of compressed JSON per output file, the first line being Parent.json, and the remaining ones each book*n*.json. You'd then have to post-process each line and pipe it into the appropriate file, and you could uncompress the line at that point.

1. Producing those multiple lines,

```
$ jq -c '.store.book as $books | .store.book = [
      { "$ref": "book\(range(1; $books | length + 1)).json" } ], $books[]' Main.json
{"store":{"book":[{"$ref":"book1.json"},{"$ref":"book2.json"}],"bicycle":{"color":"red","price":19.95}},"expensive":10}
{"category":"reference","author":"Nigel Rees","title":"Sayings of the Century","price":8.95}
{"category":"fiction","author":"Evelyn Waugh","title":"Sword of Honour","price":12.99}
```

2. Piping those lines into each their file, uncompressing each one,

```
$ jq -c '...' Main.json | (
      IFS= read -r parent
      jq . <<< "$parent" > Parent.json

      i=1
      while IFS= read -r book
      do
        jq . <<< "$book" > "book$i.json"
        i=$(($i+1))
      done
  )
```

My sh is a bit rusty, storing `read`s seems unnecessarily complicated.

---

**Update:** In the spirit of Thor's excellent solution where he splits the tasks of generating Parent.json and book*n*.json into two tasks, and solves the second part with `split` which seems pretty cut for it, I thought I'd see if I could do something similar:

```
genbooks() {
  jq -c '.store.book[]' |
  perl -nlE '$i++; open my $fh, "|jq . >book$i.json"; say $fh $_; close $fh'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it all in one go with `jq` and `coreutils`, e.g. define two functions like this:

```sh
genparent() {
  jq '.store.book = [ { "$ref": "book\(range(1; .store.book | length + 1)).json" } ]' > Parent.json
}

genbooks() {
  jq -c '.store.book[]'           |
  split --numeric-suffix=1        \
        --suffix-length=1         \
        --additional-suffix=.json \
        --filter='jq . > $FILE'   \
        --lines=1 - book
}
```

And run it like this:

```
<Main.json tee >(genparent) >(genbooks) > /dev/null
ls
```

Output:

```
book1.json  book2.json  Main.json  Parent.json
```

#### Parent.json

```
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "$ref": "book1.json"
      },
      {
        "$ref": "book2.json"
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  },
  "expensive": 10
}
```

#### book1.json

```
{
  "category": "reference",
  "author": "Nigel Rees",
  "title": "Sayings of the Century",
  "price": 8.95
}
```

#### book2.json

```
{
  "category": "fiction",
  "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
  "title": "Sword of Honour",
  "price": 12.99
}
```

Comment: This makes me thinks those two tasks should of course be split apart. :-)